# Change default audio track of Video file using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video file with extension .mkv. It contains 2 Audio Tracks.

1. English
2. Hindi

English Audio track is the default Audio track. I am trying to set the default Audio track to Hindi because when I try to play it on my LED, it plays English Audio track as it is the default track.

I used below command to set Hindi as default Audio track.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:1 output.mkv
```

But, it still keeps English as default track.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: See `-disposition` option as shown in [Mux mkv and dts file, change default audio stream and language](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/21366/).

Comment: No, both did not work. Can you send me the final command?

Comment: What did you try? I can't help if you don't provide specifics.

Answer (score 12):

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mkv" \
-map 0:0 \
-map 0:2 \
-map 0:1 \
-disposition:a:0 default \
-disposition:a:1 none \
-c copy "output.mkv"
```

1. input
2. use video stream (0:0)
3. make 2nd audio stream (Hindi) the 1st
4. make 1st audio stream (English) the 2nd
5. use the new 1st audio stream (Hindi) as default
6. remove the default from the new 2nd audio stream (English)
7. create output without transcoding

Comment: I lost several hours until I realized some players (e.g. on the web) don't support some audio formats (and the second audio track was a different format). The solution in my case was to also add `-c:a <audio_format>` to convert the audio format.

Comment: It is really important to use also `-disposition:a:1 none`, otherwise you end up having two default streams!

Answer (score 1):

```
ffmpeg -i input -map 0:v -map 0:m:language:hin -c copy output
```

Above code helped me. It worked perfectly for me.